# Buliding Windows Phone 7 projects on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-server-2008

My company is planning on developing for Windows Phone 7. The build server we have, however runs Windows Server 2008. According to the [Windows Phone SDK release notes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=190374) I've read that only Windows Server is not supported for the SDK.

Does anyone have any experience on whether there's a possible workaround to have a Windows Server 2008 machine build Windows Phone 7 projects?

**Update:** I'm interested in building on a WS 2008 as we're talking about a project with a larger team where continous integration and centralized builds are essential. I'd be hoping we wouldn't have to set up an additional Windows 7 build server for this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most the issues of this nature come into play meeting the emulator's requirements rather than the development tools.

With that said some are hacking around the walls put up to stop people going into the unsupported territory of WS2008.

Judging by your requirements I'd say dive in. If you have the option to test on device or in emulators in Win7, that will place you well.

This post likely of interest.

[Aaron Stebner's WebLog : How to install the Windows Phone Developer Tools CTP Refresh on Windows Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx)

Comment: I've used Aaron's instructions and successfully the SDK on a build server running 2008R2

Comment: Thanks Mick! Builiding on 2008 would be essential because of CI. Looking into the link you've provided.

Comment: @MickN Thanks for useful answer. Have a problem with emulator (missing MFPlat.dll). Any ideas(Win Server 2008 R2)?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is interested [here is instruction](http://pabdulin.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-windows-phone-sdk-on-windows.html) how to modify ISO image of the WinPhone 7.1 SDK for installing it on Windows Server. Basically it's the same Aaron Stebner solution, the only difference is that you need to modify it in the ISO image.