# Windows Phone 7 Automated Builds on Win2k3 server

Tags: windows-phone-7, continuous-integration

Does anyone know the best approach to setting up an automated build of a Windows Phone 7 solution on Windows 2003 server?

The SDK will only install on Win 7 or Vista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265242/buliding-windows-phone-7-projects-on-windows-server-2008) regarding setting up the tools on Windows Server 2008.
It refers to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2010/05/02/10005980.aspx and while there is no comment on using this technique with 2003 but it'll be with giving it a try.

Comment: That didn't work on Win2k3 unfortunately, the system blue-screened during the installation both times I tried it. Oh well, I guess I'll have to either upgrade to Win2k8 and try again or setup a Win7 build machine just for the phone apps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to set up the build process, the Windows Phone 7 SDK would be required. According to the [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=04704acf-a63a-4f97-952c-8b51b34b00ce), the only supported operating systems are:

> **Windows 7** and **Windows Vista**
>
> - Windows® Vista® (x86 and x64) with    Service Pack 2 – all editions except
>     Starter Edition
> - Windows 7 (x86 and x64) – all    editions except Starter Edition

Therefore, currently there is no support for Windows Server 2003 and you would have to install Windows Vista at least. This is introduced because of system-specific considerations (e.g. DirectX 10 capabilities).