# How install Windows Phone SDK on Win Server 2008R2?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I use windows server 2008r2 for development. I want try work with Windows phone 7 SDK. But it available only for Windows7 and Vista.
Is there some trick for development on WinServer?

Comment: Can you use compatibility mode during the install?

Comment: No. Installer alert "Visual studio setup cannot run in compatibility mode".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this with the v7.0 version of the tools by following the instructions at [Buliding Windows Phone 7 projects on Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265242/buliding-windows-phone-7-projects-on-windows-server-2008)

I have tried with the Mango tools though (as don't need to build on Server anymore).

Comment: If I understand the question, the problem is developing on Windows Server 2008, not just building projects there. @GraDea, can you clarify?

Comment: @VisualStuart I had previously used those instructions to install the SDK on a machine running the Server OS. With the SDK installed then there's no reason to not be able to develop on that machine also, as long as the hardware meets the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision to develop WP7 applications on Windows Server 2008 or R2.

There is a workaround to compile WP7 projects on Windows Server 2008, which supports TFS builds, but as far as development on the platform the installer prevents you from doing that. Frustrating, to say the least!